# Winforms Deployment Project running only with Administrator priviliges

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have created a deployment project for my **C#** **WinForms** application. After installing the **exe** of this deployed project, I am able to run it only as administrator. How do I make this work without ***"Run As Administrator"*** ?

Comment: Are you trying to run setup.exe as admin? Or setup.exe not as admin? Or finalinstalledexecutable.exe as admin? Or finalinstalledexecutable.exe as not admin? I am unclear from your question

Comment: I am able to install the application with "setup.exe". However, after installing I a able to run that application only when I run it as Administrator. I want to make this application run without Administrator too.

Comment: What is the name of finalinstalledexecutable.exe ? Have you used a manifest to force running as admin (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)?

Comment: I have set it as `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />`

Comment: That forces it to run as admin. You should remove that.

Comment: Removed. Yet the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145979/discussion-between-mjwills-and-yash-saraiya).

Comment: How did you go running Manifest View? What did it tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />` from your manifest file.

If that doesn't help, try Manifest View - available from https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/manifest-view-1-0 .